Airflow TriggerDagRunOperator randomly failing with parallel run
I have a DAG that is running another DAGs with TriggerDagRunOperator
trigger_1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dag1',
        trigger_dag_id='job1',
        wait_for_completion=True,
        trigger_rule='all_done',
        poke_interval=240
    )
...

When I run them as a chain
trigger_1 >> trigger_2 >> ...

Everything works fine, but once I added parallelizing, trigger tasks starts randomly failing, even when the child DAGs have rule all_success and they completed correctly
[trigger_1, trigger_2] >> trigger_3 >> [trigger_4, trigger_5]

There is no logs for task job. I see only:
*** The task might not have been executed, logs were deleted as part of logs retention (default of 30 days),  or worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g. was evicted).

I checked CPU and other resources etc. during the run, it is less than 50%.
I checked max_active_runs_per_dag=25 and dag_concurrency=100
And I run just 2 DAGs in parallel. Sometime first group finished successfully, but then next group failing.
Update:
Seems TriggerDagRunOperator operator fails when child DAG have retry tasks, but how to avoid it mark as Failed, I didn't find a solution yet

Which Executor does your instance of Airflow run on ? Is it CeleryExecutor or another one ? This might help find an answer.

It seems like the issue you're experiencing with the TriggerDagRunOperator failing when running parallel tasks, particularly with child DAGs that have retry tasks, could be related to how Airflow tracks the state of the triggered DAGs.
Check Child DAG’s Task States
When the child DAG's tasks are retrying, the TriggerDagRunOperator might interpret the DAG run as incomplete or failed, even though the tasks eventually succeed. To avoid this, make sure all tasks within the child DAG are properly set up for retries. If retries are causing failures, you might want to set wait_for_completion=False so the parent DAG doesn't wait for the child DAG to finish entirely
.
